# how to fix a mongoose strictmode error on an updateOne?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, strict, express-router

i have a model like this :

**Mongoose Schema**

```
var LinkedinUpdateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  likes:{values:[PersonSchema],
    _total: Number},
  numLikes: Number,
  timestamp: Number,
  updateComments:{
    values:[CommentSchema],
    _total: Number
  },
  updateContent:{
    companyStatusUpdate:{
      share:{
        comment: String,
        timestamp: Number
      }
    }
  },
});
```

**Router**

```
  router.post('/:type',function(req,res,next){
  if(cutFilename.includes(req.params.type)){
    var object = require('./models/'+req.params.type);
    object.UpdateOne(req.body,req.body,{upsert:true,strict:false},function(err,object){
      if(err) console.log(err)
      res.json(object);
    })
  }else{
    res.json('error: type: '+ req.params.type + 'not found !');
  }
});
```

so i am trying to achieve a post function that does not allow duplicates and so i found the {upsert:true} in an updateOne. this worked perfectly until i had to make a call that filters out some data. so i get a batch of data and i only want to get the data that fits in the model.

but because not everything is defined in the model i get a StrictMode error. and when i disable the strictMode i get all the data that wasnt even defined in the model.

**evidence of this occurrence**

[image]

as you can see here isCommentable, islikable and isliked has been added without it being defined. and i know this is because i put {strict:false} but if i do not add this is, no data gets added and i get the following error:

> { StrictModeError: Path "updateType" is not in schema, strict mode is `true`, and upsert is `true`.

so i was wondering how can i fix this without adding anything to my model or using the {strict:false}.

Hopefully anyone can help me with this, anymore info that is necessary: name it and i will edit it in.

Comment: unfortunantly this did not work. its still gets added to my database.

Comment: You have to remove the unwanted keys before `$set`  in update.

Comment: what do you mean with $set ? i do not use the $set because i use it as an non-duplicating post/create function.

Comment: hi did u find a solution for this.?

Comment: @JohnsonCherian its better for you to make your own question because it is depending on the mongoose model/schema and the call you are executing.